# Inequality involving a strictly positive sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, limsup-and-liminf

I was asked to prove the following :
\begin{array}{l}
 x_n  > 0,\,\forall n \in Z^ +   \\ 
 \lim \sup (\frac{{x_{n + 1}  + x_1 }}{{x_n }})^n  \ge e \\ 
 \end{array} 
Is my approach correct ?
Using reductio ad absurdum I intend to prove that for any natural number $k$ there is a natural number $n$ such that $\
n \ge k,\,\frac{{x_{n + 1}  + x_1 }}{{x_n }} \ge 1 + \frac{1}{n}
\
$ .
We hereby assume the contrary, namely for any natural number $k$ there is a natural number $n$ satisfying : $\
\frac{{x_{n + 1}  + x_1 }}{{x_n }} < 1 + \frac{1}{n}
\
$.
Then $\
\frac{{x_n }}{n} - \frac{{x_{n + 1} }}{{n + 1}} > \frac{{x_1 }}{{n + 1}}
\
$ .
Upon summation for $\
n = k,k + 1,...,k + s
\
$ we get :

---

$$\
\frac{{x_k }}{k} - \frac{{x_{k + s} }}{{k + s}} > x_1 (\frac{1}{{k + 1}} + \frac{1}{{k + 2}} + ... + \frac{1}{{k + s}})
\
$$

---

Since the RHS is unbounded we conclude that the contrary is true :$\
\begin{array}{l}
 n \ge k,\,\frac{{x_{n + 1}  + x_1 }}{{x_n }} \ge 1 + \frac{1}{n} =  >  \\ 
  =  > \lim \sup (\frac{{x_{n + 1}  + x_1 }}{{x_n }})^n  \ge \lim \sup (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n  \\ 
 \end{array}
\
$

Hence $$\
lim\sup (\frac{{x_{n + 1}  + x_1 }}{{x_n }})^n  \ge e
\
$$

Some of my peers suggested that the inequality in the box might be wrong in several cases, depending on our choosing of $x_n$  - e.g. $x_n=n^5$ - but I feel that it should  hold no matter how $x_n$  looks like (with respect tot the original condition).

Is my proof correct ? Moreover, if my inequality holds for any $x_n>0$ how can I give a formal proof of this fact ?

Comment: It isgood enough!

Comment: Your proof looks correct. (I would insert $\frac{x_k}{k} > x_1\left(\frac1{k+1}+\ldots+\frac1{k+s}\right)$ to make the main step clearer.) For $x_n=n^5$ the limit is $e^5$...